# JQuery selecting inner div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given this HTML

```
 <div class="list">Item 1
   <div class="hidden">This is the rest of the data</div>
</div>
```

I need to select only the content of the inner div tag.

I have this JQuery function but I can't seem to get to the inner tag.

```
$( ".list" ).click(function() {
  var htmlString = $( this ).html();
  alert(htmlString)
 });
```

Comment: Try using .children() instead of .html()

Answer (score 1):

Use `find()`:

```
$( ".list" ).click(function() {
  var htmlString = $( this ).find('div.hidden').html();
  alert(htmlString)
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also you `first()`

```
$( ".list" ).click(function() {
  var htmlString = $( this ).first().html();
  alert(htmlString)
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner div appears to be a first child of the `.list` div, so it is selectable by `firstChild()`.

```
$( ".list" ).click(function() {
  var htmlString = $( this ).firstChild().html();
  alert(htmlString)
 });
```

Also, as you know the class of inner div, why not just do:

```
$( ".hidden" ).click(function() {
  var htmlString = $( this ).html();
  alert(htmlString)
 });
```

Another solution:

```
$( ".list > div" ).click(function() {
  var htmlString = $( this ).html();
  alert(htmlString)
 });
```

And actually there are tons of ways to solve this problem, not going to post every one :D